# When does a Gaussian Process' precision matrix have zeros in it?

Tags: gaussian-process

... or equivalently, when does a Gaussian Process have a "sparse structure" which is mentioned in [this talk about sparse GPs by Richard Turner](https://youtu.be/sQmsQq_Jfi8?t=34m30s)?

In the talk, it's mentioned that if the precision matrix of a multivariate normal has zeros in it, then there are conditional independencies within the model. I understand this (the density factorizes) but when exactly does the precision matrix end up with zeros in it?

Is it due to the positive semi-definiteness of the covariance matrix? Is this due to a particular kernel?

Comment: The precision associated to a pair $i,j$ will be zero if and only if they are conditionally independent given all other variables. This can happen for all sorts of reasons, any time the dependence structure can be described by a non-complete Markov graph. A special case which is common is the class of conditional auto-regressive models. In the case of sparse GPs, you can also represent the approximating GP with a simple graph which connects the inducing data to the observed data.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @guy ! Is there a way to prove the emergence of a Markov graph given just a covariance function $k(x, x')$ and the grid points $x$ (without actually inverting the covariance matrix)?

Comment: This does occur for some kernels. For example, in one dimension the Laplace kernel $k(x,x') =  a\exp(b|x-x'|)$ induces this property. But it is tricky using a covariance function to get this property because the covariance function encodes marginal, rather than conditional, dependencies.

Comment: @guy well, the idea I had was that given the fact that a GP is completely encoded by the kernel (ignoring the mean), the grid and the kernel are the only possible changes one could make to the model to induce this behavior

Comment: To some extent, right, the kernel determines the sparsity pattern. The point is that it is difficult to get this behavior by working with the kernel directly; it is easier to get sparsity by working with a graphical model, and have the structure of the kernel be determined implicitly by that. Sparsity in the precision matrix encodes conditional independence, while sparsity in the kernel encodes marginal independence, so it is easier to work with the precision.

Comment: This makes sense. One follow up question: would it be possible for you to give me an example of a kernel $k(x, x') = f(||x - x'||^p)$ for some function f and positive real p that's monotonic decreasing w.r.t the norm which _doesn't_ lead to the sparsity structure?

Comment: It is harder to give an example of one that does lead to sparsity than one that does not. Squared exponential, Laplace, etc., will all fail to yield sparsity; Laplace kernel only works in one dimension because you can separate two points using a point rather than requiring a curve.